# interactive shiny global date picker

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working with R in an environment that doesn't have a good date picker and I'm trying to pop up a date picker using R to fill in the gap.

Most R date pickers require UI libraries like GTK. Shiny's doesn't.
All I'd like to do is pop up a date picker, let the user choose the date and then end the shiny session and pass the date back to continue the R script.

Here's what I have so far, but no success. I'm trying to assign the date to a global variable x.

```
library("shiny")
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {

  ui <- fluidPage(
    # Default value is the date in client's time zone
    dateInput("date2", "Date:"),
    verbatimTextOutput("date2")

  )

  shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output) {
  reactive(x <<- input$date2)

  })
}
```

But the variable x doesn't show up in the global env.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you're never calling that reactive object. In server, you'd have to do something like:

```
shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$date2, {x <<- input$date2})
})
```

This way, a change in `input$date2` will trigger the global assignment of x.

Comment: Shiny loads reactive objects only when they are needed (called in ui). So if you want something to just lurk in the background and update no matter what the user does, the `observe` family of functions are your friend!

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like this, where you assign the value to the global env when the session ends.

```
library("shiny")
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Default value is the date in client's time zone
  dateInput("date2", "Date:"),
  verbatimTextOutput("date2")

)

shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output, session) {
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    assign("x", isolate(dat()), pos =  .GlobalEnv)
  })
  dat <- reactive({
    req(input$date2); 
    x <- input$date2
    x
    })
})
```